# value of FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED while creating a sql database

Tags: android, sql, database

I am creating a sql database in my app and I am following the documentation on the official developer guide of android, at the webpage 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow.
I don't understand what is the meaning of the  `FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED` value.
What should is value be? What does it mean actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the name of the update column in the feed table ;)

```
// How you want the results sorted in the resulting Cursor
String sortOrder = FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_UPDATED + " DESC";
```

Comment: ok it means that it is just a column in the table right? no special meaning

Comment: what it was not clear is why it is called "updated", this name makes it a bit unclear...

Comment: yes, exactly ;) but it's a column name. You should know as this is SQL basics.

Comment: sorry I'm new to the field, i'm trying to learn by programming :) thanks :)